# Why did my app crash when assigning self to __weak local under ARC?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references

Crashlytics reported this crash:

```
0    libobjc.A.dylib     _objc_trap() + 18446744073709552000
1    libobjc.A.dylib     _objc_fatal + 71
2    libobjc.A.dylib     append_referrer_no_lock(weak_referrer_array_t*, objc_object**)
3    libobjc.A.dylib     objc_storeWeak + 120
4    MyApp               CloudSyncButton.m line 58 -[CloudSyncButton observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:]
5    ....
```

The code in question:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    CloudSyncButton* __weak weakSelf = self;  //<---crashed here
    if([keyPath isEqualToString:kCloudSyncingKVO]) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            CloudSyncButton* localSelf = weakSelf;
            [localSelf refreshCloudSyncIcon];
        });
    }
}
```

I need help understanding why this crashed and what I can do to avoid it in the future.  This is the first time I've seen something like this crash, so I'm wondering if it is a fluke?

Comment: Try `__weak CloudSyncButton* weakSelf = self;`.

Comment: @Adam - Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) says: You should decorate variables correctly. When using qualifiers in an object variable declaration, the correct format is:`ClassName * qualifier variableName;`  `__weak` is a qualifier

Comment: Didn't know that. I always place the qualifier first. Thanks for update.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure that in all cases your CloudSyncButton has removed itself from observing other objects in its dealloc method. It would appear this message is getting sent after your button has been deallocated.

Comment: I do remove observers on dealloc.  Is it possible that there's a race condition between the object being deallocated and storing a weak reference?

Comment: If threads are involved, possibly, not really sure. I guess you cannot reproduce this in your testing, its coming in from a bug report. If possible remove the observers when your button is removed from the superview (by subclassing removeFromSuperview). Everyone doing KVO on Mac programs has had problems with either not removing objects, or observing them more than once, etc.

Comment: It seems plausible that I'll avoid some headaches with this situation if I remove the observers during `removeFromSuperview`.  Thanks!

Comment: Its going to be really hard to know for sure what's happening with one lone crash. When this happens to me I just try to tighten things up a bit. The observeValueForKeyPath does the callbacks when the value changes, regardless of thread. If it happens while the main thread is half way through a dealloc, who knows what might happen. Good luck!